Visual Studio 2022 linker errors when using multiple projects
I have a c++ solution that consists of three projects. One project accesses classes from the other projects. The solution compiles but won’t build with linker errors, ie unresolved external symbol.
The other projects have been added as project references.
How do I resolve the unresolved references?

C++ does not work like C#, w.r.t. reusable classes. "Project references" in VisualC++ only work when you're using C++/CLI (i.e. C++ compiled to IL for .NET). In a "real" C++ project you need to either use source file sharing, staticatically linking .lib, or using COM/WinRT for class exports and reuse.

Thanks I thought that might be the case. So how do I get the unit testing framework to work?

"the" unit testing framework?

For example if I use Native unit test project in visual studio. When I do this the unit test project won't build because all the classes in the project I am trying to test result in unresolved references

You need to add a linker-reference to the source project's output .lib/.obj files.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2022#object_files

Thanks very much for your input. I did some experimenting and adding the .obj as the linker reference works. The only downside is that I need to add all the objects individually. But at least it works. Thanks again.

If you use a Glob pattern (e.g. /**) then you won't need to add all references individually, if they're in the same directory.
